# How to read typed array with another arrays type

Tags: javascript, arrays, typed-arrays

I am inside a function, `array1` and `array2` are it's paramentrs which are typed arrays, any of these: `Uint32Array`or`Int32Array`or`Float64Array`or`Uint8Array`
Inside this function how can I convert `array1` raw data into a typed array equal to `array2` type
something like this:

```
function readArray(array1, array2)
{
    var a = new array2Type(array1.buffer);
    //rest of the code where "a" is used
}
```

`array2Type` is not a valid code, what would be the correct way to do the conversion?

Comment: Your post is not very clear for me.

Comment: So what does `array2` contain?

Comment: 2nd edit version of question, is it the clearest now?

Comment: if it's clear now, I would like an upvote to avoid people jumping over my question in the main page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new typed array view based on a source one doing this:

```
var dstArray = new window[srcArray.constructor.name](srcArray.buffer);
```

Implemented in the function:

```js
function readArray(array1, array2) {
  var a = new window[array2.constructor.name](array1.buffer);
  console.log(a.constructor.name);
}

var a1 = new Uint32Array(1);
var a2 = new Float32Array(1);
readArray(a1, a2); //Should log Float32Array
```

You will however need to add some sanitizing as for example a `Uint32Array` need four bytes as a minimum, and if you pass in a 1-length `Uint16Array` it will fail since there are only two bytes. And so forth.